# combining txt files which have no column headers

Tags: windows-10, text-files

I have a large number of txt files supplied to me by a third party, each containing two columns of string data.  The data format is completely consistent but there are no column headers.

I'm trying to combine them all into one file. The simple way to do this usually is by opening the windows command prompt in the file location and using say copy *.txt MyMergedFile.txt.  In this case it copies the contents of the last file on the list to my new file and ignores the others.  I assumed that this is because of the lack of headers?  Is there a way to either quickly and easily insert headers into all my files, so I can use the usual method, or a simple way of combining these without headers? Happy to use PowerShell, SQL2008, R, vb, whatever has the lowest hassle factor. I'm working in Windows 10.  The application is building a large lookup table in a GIS geodatabase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this in R using the following:

```
#get tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
# make a list of target files, i.e. all the .txts in my designated folder
files<-list.files(path = "C:/temp/myfiles", pattern = "*.txt", full.names = T)
# quick check to make sure they are all there
print files
# put the contents into one file
masterfile<- sapply(files, read.table, simplify=FALSE) %>% bind_rows()
```

From here I can read my data into a suitable format for the next stage in my workflow.

Comment: Apologies, I omitted to credit the source of the solution. I adapted a solution from a blog post I found on data science: https://blog.exploratory.io/how-to-read-multiple-excel-or-csv-files-together-42af5d314a10I